# ValueError: I/O operation on closed csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, io

The code below shows I/O error on a closed file even after the correct indentation. Where might the error be coming from? Kindly check on the function call as well, I'm a beginner and there might be errors there as well.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import csv

win= Tk()
win.resizable(0, 0)
win.title('ADD PRODUCT')

global text_input
global int_input1
global int_input2
global int_input3
global int_input4

text_input=StringVar()
int_input1=IntVar()
int_input2=IntVar()
int_input3=IntVar()
int_input4=IntVar()

with open('products_database.csv', 'w', newline='') as x:
        fieldnames=('Barcode', 'item', 'sales_price', 'purchase_price',    'reorder_level')
        writer=csv.DictWriter(x, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()

        def saver():
                with open('products_database.csv', 'a', newline='') as y:
                        writer.writerow({'Barcode':int_input1.get(), 'item':text_input.get(),'sales_price':int_input2.get(),'purchase_price':int_input3.get(), 'reorder_level':int_input4.get()})
                        y.close()

def clear():
        operator=text_input.set('')
        operator=int_input1.set('')
        operator=int_input2.set('')
        operator=int_input3.set('')
        operator=int_input4.set('')

a=Label(win, text='Scan barcode').grid(column=0, row=0)
b=Entry(win, text=int_input1).grid(column=1, row=0)
c=Label(win, text='Item').grid(column=0, row=1)
d=Entry(win, text=text_input).grid(column=1, row=1)
e=Label(win, text='Sale price').grid(column=0, row=2)
f=Entry(win, text=int_input2).grid(column=1, row=2)
h=Label(win, text='Purchase price').grid(column=0, row=3)
i=Entry(win, text=int_input3).grid(column=1, row=3)
j=Label(win, text='Reorder level').grid(column=0, row=4)
k=Entry(win, text=int_input4).grid(column=1, row=4)
l=Button(win, text='Clear', width=20, command=clear).grid(column=0, row=5,    columnspan=1)
m=Button(win, text='Save', width=20, command=saver).grid(column=1, row=5)
```

Comment: why would you define a function inside a `with` statement? why close a file at the end of a `with` statment?

Comment: Hello, I understand on the file closing. But i had put a function inside the with statement so that I can call it as a command in one of the buttons. Calling the whole with statement is resulting in writing headers all over the csv document. I need the program to write headers once and then append rows with each calling.

Comment: Are you able to suggest better code/syntax?

Answer (score 0):

when you define a function that uses variables from its outer scope it will keep a reference to those variables so it can use them when you call it, but when you use a `with` statement the file closes as you exit it so by the time you call `saver` `x` would already be closed then you try to use `writer` which uses `x` and it fails. try defining the `saver` function outside of the part that saves the headers and make its own csv writer like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import csv

win= Tk()
win.resizable(0, 0)
win.title('ADD PRODUCT')

global text_input
global int_input1
global int_input2
global int_input3
global int_input4

text_input=StringVar()
int_input1=IntVar()
int_input2=IntVar()
int_input3=IntVar()
int_input4=IntVar()

with open('products_database.csv', 'w') as x:
    fieldnames=('Barcode', 'item', 'sales_price', 'purchase_price',  'reorder_level')
    writer=csv.DictWriter(x, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

def saver():
    with open('products_database.csv', 'a') as y:
        writer=csv.DictWriter(y, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writerow({'Barcode':int_input1.get(), 'item':text_input.get(),'sales_price':int_input2.get(),'purchase_price':int_input3.get(), 'reorder_level':int_input4.get()})

def clear():
    operator=text_input.set('')
    operator=int_input1.set('')
    operator=int_input2.set('')
    operator=int_input3.set('')
    operator=int_input4.set('')

a=Label(win, text='Scan barcode').grid(column=0, row=0)
b=Entry(win, text=int_input1).grid(column=1, row=0)
c=Label(win, text='Item').grid(column=0, row=1)
d=Entry(win, text=text_input).grid(column=1, row=1)
e=Label(win, text='Sale price').grid(column=0, row=2)
f=Entry(win, text=int_input2).grid(column=1, row=2)
h=Label(win, text='Purchase price').grid(column=0, row=3)
i=Entry(win, text=int_input3).grid(column=1, row=3)
j=Label(win, text='Reorder level').grid(column=0, row=4)
k=Entry(win, text=int_input4).grid(column=1, row=4)
l=Button(win, text='Clear', width=20, command=clear).grid(column=0, row=5,  columnspan=1)
m=Button(win, text='Save', width=20, command=saver).grid(column=1, row=5)
```

also you don't need to call `y.close()` since it's inside the `with` statement (although that is not the source of the error, files can be closed any number of times but just the first one will actually have any effect)